# Как сортировать HashMap по значениям?

Tags: java, map, hashmap

Как сортировать HashMap по значениям?

```
HashMap<GridPane, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал TreeMap из LinkedHashMap, но ругается на мою конструкцию.

Comment: Сортировать обычный HashMap не получится, потому что эта коллекция по своей сути не гарантирует никакого порядка ключей / значений. Вам стоит использовать другой тип данных для хранения, например LinkedHashMap. Если же задача стоит не в хранении значений, уточните пожалуйста вопрос.

Comment: 'List<Map.Entry<GridPane, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());'  Вместо TreeMap. Получаете список вхождений, его и передаете в sort()

Comment: GridPane в List<Map.Entry<GridPane, Integer>> list  не может скушать. А вот String срабатывает. Как это работает не понимаю.

Comment: Опять же что пишет?

Comment: `Collections.sort` принимает на вход объект типа `List`, а вы ему пытаетесь подсунуть `Map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`.

```
Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2) {
        return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
    }
});
```

Получить `List` можно передав в конструктор `map.getEntrySet()`
После того как вы получите отсортированный список добавьте каждый элемент по очереди в `Map`

Comment: И в map останется прежний порядок

Comment: Да, надо в конце использовать LinkedHashMap, он сохраняет порядок в котором элементы были добавлены

Comment: Чет у меня проблемы с применением этого компаратора. Помогите переварить пожалуйста.

Comment: Какие проблемы? отредактируйте вопрос, без чего-то конкретного сложновато будет

Comment: Благодарю. LinkedHashMap спас, но компаратором пользоваться пока не научился )

Comment: Посмотрите на простых примерах, там ничего сложного как такового нет)

Answer (score 1):

`HasMap` не даст отсортировать элементы внутри себя, т.к. это не упорядоченная коллекция и расположение элементов в нем зависит от их хэшкодов. Используйте `ThreeMap` в конструктор которого можно передать компаратор который будет производить сравнение элементов. Сортировка будет производиться по ключу.

Comment: Ну а как отсортировать по значению? TreeMap  я сделал из LinkedHashMap. Применить вышеуказанную конструкцию не получается

Comment: @alex По значениям никак, возможно в вашей ситуации нужна какая то другая коллекция а не `Map`